# Свой шрифт в WebView JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, webview

Подключил к WebView JavaFX 17 шрифт, которого нет в системе. WebView некорректно его отображает. Причем, шрифты, установленные в систему он отображает нормально. После Font.loadFont, шрифт появляется в списке шрифтов, но отображается неверно.
Подскажите, что делаю не так?

Код sample.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="750.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="myLabel" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="730.0" text="Select Font">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font></Label>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="myWebPane" layoutX="220.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="420.0" prefWidth="520.0">
         <children>
            <WebView fx:id="myWebView" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="5.0" prefHeight="410.0" prefWidth="510.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <ListView fx:id="myListView" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="70.0" onMouseClicked="#handleMouseClickEvent" prefHeight="420.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

код Controller.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> myListView;

    @FXML
    private Label myLabel;

    @FXML
    private WebView myWebView;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane myWebPane;

    private String fontText = "";


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        myLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        myLabel.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
        myListView.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
        myWebPane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
        Font myFont = Font.loadFont(getClass().getResource("TRON.TTF").toExternalForm(), 10);
        String myFamily = myFont.getFamily();
        System.out.println("Font family = " + myFamily);
        ObservableList<String> fontsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Font.getFontNames());
        myListView.setItems(fontsList);
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleMouseClickEvent() {
        changeFont();
    }

    private void changeFont() {
        Font useFont = Font.font(myListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(), 24);
        String fontFamily = useFont.getFamily();
        myLabel.setText("Now use font " + useFont.getName() +
                " and his font-family is " + fontFamily);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fontText);
        sb.setLength(0);
        sb.append("<p style='font-family:")
          .append(myListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem())
          .append(";font-size:24'>The quick brown fox jump 1234567890</p>");
          System.out.println("Now Use Font " + myListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        fontText = sb.toString();
        myWebView.getEngine().loadContent(fontText);
    }
}
```

код Main.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Fonts in WebView");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Шрифт лежит рядом с файлами:

[image: Скрин директорий проекта]

А вот отображение шрифта:
[image: Отображение шрифта]

Вот как должен отображаться:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, к примеру, отображение установленного в систему шрифта Georgia:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

OS Debian, Intellij Idea 2020.3, Java 17, OpenJavaFX javafx-sdk-17.0.2

Comment: Давно писал на JavaFX, если мне нужно было добавить свой шрифт, я использовал такой код в css файле проекта. После этого можно к нему обращаться, например:
@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto Mono";
    src: url("fonts/RobotoMono-VariableFont_wght.ttf");
    font-family: "Soft";
    src: url("fonts/softBold.ttf");
}
.menu {
    -fx-font-family: "Roboto Mono";
    -fx-font-size: 14;
}

Comment: Поддерживаю комент выше, всё что касается стилей лучше подгружать отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

Всем добрый день. Возможно кому-нибудь пригодится. Нашел причину того, почему не отображался шрифт. Загрузку шрифта нужно производить либо в начале метода start(Stage primaryStage) до инициализации формы sample.fxml, либо в объявлении переменных класса Controller.
Вот код контроллера, при котором шрифт отображается нормально:

```
package sample;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    Font myFont = Font.loadFont(getClass().getResource("TRON.TTF").toExternalForm(), 10);

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> myListView;

    @FXML
    private Label myLabel;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane myWebPane;

    private String fontText = "";

    @FXML
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        myLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        myLabel.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
        myListView.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
        myWebPane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
        String myFamily = myFont.getFamily();
        System.out.println("Font family = " + myFamily);
        ObservableList<String> fontsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Font.getFontNames());
        myListView.setItems(fontsList);
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleMouseClickEvent() {
        changeFont();
    }

    private void changeFont() {
        Font useFont = Font.font(myListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        String fontFamily = useFont.getFamily();
        myLabel.setText("Now use font " + useFont.getName() +
                " and his font-family is " + fontFamily);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fontText);
        sb.setLength(0);
        sb.append("<p style='font-family:")
                .append(myListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem())
                .append(";font-size:24;'>The quick brown fox jump 1234567890</p>");
        System.out.println("Now Use Font " + myListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        fontText = sb.toString();
        myWebView.getEngine().loadContent(fontText);
    }
}
```

Вот скрин нормального отображения шрифта:
[image: Нормальное отображение шрифта]